# How to check idle time

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I have created a method for the `KeyUp` event for a `TextBlock`, which filters contacts. All this works fine.

Now, instead of filtering on every `KeyUp` event, I want to check if the user is idle for 1-1.5 secs. before triggering the filter method.

I am absolutely new to C#, so I do not even know how to approach this problem. How can I achieve this?

Comment: What determines `idling`? And what is the reasoning behind delaying the filtering?

Comment: @Cheesebaron when the user stops typing

Comment: Use a timer and filter it there

Comment: @SriramSakthivel yep, pretty obvious. I'm just stuck with c#'s syntax and the big wide world of the .net framework.

Comment: Provide some code and help me to understand what you're trying. So that I can help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to time anything in C# then your best bet is to try using

`StopWatch` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.aspx

```
    Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
    stopWatch.Start();
    stopWatch.Stop();
    // Get the elapsed time as a TimeSpan value.
    TimeSpan ts = stopWatch.Elapsed;
```

I am looking through the documentation and I cant seem to find the StopWatch Library so here is an alt solution I know works
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx

```
//  DispatcherTimer setup
dispatcherTimer = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tick);
dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0,0,1);
dispatcherTimer.Start();

private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //check your users text
}
```